# Convert Char to Int or vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I'm having trouble getting the right conversion without removing any values from the output.

I'd like to join two tables, but the primary key on one table is a `char(4)` and the other one has it as an `INT`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
select A.ID,
B.ID from 
TableA A
 left join tableB B on
 cast(a.ID as varchar(4) = B.ID
```

I realized that this does not bring single digit values.

```
Table A values: 0,1,2,3,41
Table B values: 0,1,2,3,41
```

My output with my original query only gives me 41 and forgets about the other 4 values.

I need to be able to get the other 4 values

Any ideas on how I can get my desired out put?

Comment: If you're only storing `int` values in the `varchar` why not fix the datatype and change the column to an `int`? Performing a `JOIN` on a `int` -> `varchar` is going to perform slowly, as no index is going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this out using temp tables and it all works as expected (I did add a closing `)`)

```
create table #tableA(id int)
insert #tablea (id) values (0), (1), (2), (3), (41)
create table #tableb(id char(4))
insert #tableb (id) values (0), (1), (2), (3), (41)

select A.ID,
B.ID from 
#TableA A
 left join #tableB B on
 cast(a.ID as varchar(4)) = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* convert to strings:

```
select A.ID, B.ID
from  TableA A left join
      tableB B
      on cast(a.ID as varchar(4)) = B.ID;
```

As I've learned from painful experience, this does not handle leading zeros or 0 decimals.  So `0.00` is not the same as `000`.  However, this should be fine for single digits unless there is zero padding.

For numeric comparisons, go in the other direction

```
select A.ID, B.ID
from  TableA A left join
      tableB B
      on a.ID = try_convert(int, B.ID);
```

Of course, the real solution is to fix your tables so the columns have the same data type.